# SQL Server Query to return all Stored Procedures, Functions, Tables and Views with their Parameters / Columns

Tags: sql-server

I need a SQL Server query (preferably for SQL Server 2012+) that will return a list of all non-system stored procedures, functions, tables and views and that will also return a simple list of all their associated parameters / column names.

The simple list should be something like a CSV, although JSON is preferred.

The objective is to be able to run the query and get a list of entities with enough information to be able to construct further queries / execute statements to a basic level.

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering my own question.  I found a lot of the answers related to much older versions of SQL Server.  But I also found a lot of the answers were fragmentary and I wanted something that was a bit 'better' (hopefully) as a starting point.

Here it is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  QUOTENAME(isc2.TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(isc2.TABLE_NAME) AS sqlEntName
  , 'TV' AS sqlEntType 
  , '{' + SUBSTRING((
    SELECT ',\"' + isc1.COLUMN_NAME + '\":\"' + isc1.DATA_TYPE + '\" ' 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS isc1 
    WHERE QUOTENAME(isc1.TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(isc1.TABLE_NAME) 
      = QUOTENAME(isc2.TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(isc2.TABLE_NAME) 
    ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION 
    FOR XML PATH ('')
  ), 2, 1024) + '}' AS sqlClmPrmNames 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS isc2
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT 
  QUOTENAME(isp2.SPECIFIC_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(isp2.SPECIFIC_NAME) AS sqlEntName
  , 'SF' AS sqlEntType 
  , ISNULL('{' + SUBSTRING((
    SELECT ',\"' + isp1.PARAMETER_NAME + '\":\"' + isp1.DATA_TYPE + '\" '
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARAMETERS isp1
    WHERE QUOTENAME(isp1.SPECIFIC_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(isp1.SPECIFIC_NAME) NOT IN 
      (SELECT QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id)) + '.' + QUOTENAME(name)
      FROM  sys.all_objects
      WHERE is_ms_shipped = 1 AND [type] IN ('P'))
    AND QUOTENAME(isp1.SPECIFIC_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(isp1.SPECIFIC_NAME) 
      = QUOTENAME(isp2.SPECIFIC_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(isp2.SPECIFIC_NAME)
    ORDER BY QUOTENAME(isp1.SPECIFIC_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(isp1.SPECIFIC_NAME)
      , isp1.ORDINAL_POSITION 
    FOR XML PATH ('')
  ), 2, 1024) + '}', '{}') AS sqlClmPrmNames 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARAMETERS isp2
WHERE isp2.SPECIFIC_NAME NOT LIKE '%diagram%' -- You may need to remove this final filter clause
```

This will yield three columns, the first with the name of the entity, the second with the 'type' (either 'TV' for table or view, or 'SF' for stored procedure or function), and the third with a JSON-esque list of column names / parameter names.

Comment: ***Triggers, Types, Rules, Defaults..*** ?